# Can I create iPhone application in visual studio cordova without mac system?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I do not have mac system. I want ipk file from my cordova application in visual studio 2015.
Is it possible without mac system ?
Is the any simulator for iPhone for window 10 ?

Comment: If you're serious about iOS development then you you're going to need a Mac - even a cheap Mac Mini from eBay will do.

Comment: Is there any iPhone Emulator for windows 10 ?

Comment: No, there is no iPhone simulator for windows.

Comment: I search lot but I also did not found.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't an emulator available. The only way to do iOS development at this point is to have some kind of OS X installation to use as a build machine. How you manage to get the OS X is up to you, but the simplest and most hassle free way is to get a (second hand, maybe?) Mac.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you need a mac with an apple developer account for compilation. See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/cli/index.html under Add Platforms

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit of information. You need a mac to be able to generate the necessary certificates and provisioning profile (More info [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/signing_signing-ios.md.html)). Of course for this you will also need a Apple Developer account. That's all you need a Mac for.

Once you have those then you can build iOS applications via [Phonegap Cloud Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) and deploy the iOS app to your testers using something like [DeployGate](https://deploygate.com/dashboard).

I got my colleague (who owns a mac) to generate those certificate for me. Since then I have been developing for Android and iOS without using a Mac again.